# How to input file to julia script in command line

Tags: julia

Say that I have script.jl and file.txt.
At the moment I read the file within the script. (with the path hard coded)

What I would like to do is to type:

```
julia script.jl /path/to/file.txt
```

in the command line (linux), and then handle the file in the script. How to do this?

Thanks in advance! 
Mathias

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. The array ARGS holds the command line arguments :)