# Accessing command line arguments as a txt file in Julia

Tags: command-line, julia

If I write

$julia prog.jl foo bar baz

I can access foo bar baz as ARGS[1],ARGS[2],ARGS[3] respectively.

For my program, there's many more inputs so I want to do something like

$julia prog.jl inputs.txt

and then within prog.jl I want to read inputs.txt. If I naively just have read(ARGS) in prog.jl it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766911/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-read-text-file-using-julia shows several ways to read a file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745869/how-to-input-file-to-julia-script-in-command-line explains how to access the command line (though you apparently already know that part). Which aspect of this are you having trouble with, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

```
const args = split(read(ARGS[1], String), r"\s+")
```

This line in your program's beginning should get your list of inputs, assuming that inputs.txt is the first argument. The line reads the file as a string and then splits on whitespace, so whitespace cannot occur within a file name using this method (whitespace would not be allowed without quotes with the command line file names method either).